# Swift present view shows layer the top

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation controller, where its root view controller is a logIn View controller, when the user login, it calls present(..) to display a different screen, but I have something special on the display. As the picture shows, it shows the layers between two screens. I am not able to remove such behavior. My app is without storyboard.

code:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    naviVC = UINavigationController()
    naviVC?.viewControllers = [loginVc!]
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    window?.rootViewController = naviVC
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.windowScene = windowScene
}
```

Later when I calls this at loginVC:

```
//nextVC is the next viewController here.
self.present(self.nextVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Output as the picture shows:
[See the top, the green is the loginVC, the white is the nextVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqGU4.png)

How can I fix it, so the nextVC will cover the LoginVC?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the documentation for more information -> [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/modality/)

> Defaults to UIModalPresentationAutomatic on iOS starting in iOS 13.0, and UIModalPresentationFullScreen on previous versions.
>   By default UIViewController resolves UIModalPresentationAutomatic to UIModalPresentationPageSheet, but other system-provided view controllers may resolve UIModalPresentationAutomatic to other concrete presentation styles.

---

You can still force to do what you want ->

```swift
let controller = UIViewController()
controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen // or you can use `.overFullScreen` for transparency
present(controller, animated: true)
```

**BONUS**

[View Controller Presentation Changes in iOS 13](https://medium.com/@hacknicity/view-controller-presentation-changes-in-ios-13-ac8c901ebc4e)

Answer (score 0):

Insert it `nextVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen` before `self.present(self.nextVC, animated: false, completion: nil)`

result:

```
nextVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

self.present(self.nextVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
```